# PHP Lock on file before unlink

Tags: php, concurrency, filesystems, locking, unlink

I wanted to wait for all processes reading a certain file in PHP by obtaining an exclusive lock on that file, and after that delete (unlink) the file. This concerns files like profile pictures which a user can delete or change. The name of the file will be something like the user ID.

My code:

```
//Obtain lock
$file = fopen("path/to/file", "r"); //(I'm not sure which mode to use here btw)
flock($file, LOCK_EX);

//Delete file
unlink("path/to/file");
```

Line 3 waits for all locks to be released, which is good, but the `unlink` function throws an error: `Warning: unlink(path/to/file): Resource temporarily unavailable in path/to/script on line xx`

To prevent this I could release the lock before calling `unlink`, but this means another process could lock on the file again, which would cause the same error.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to delete a file in PHP without releasing the lock? That is, without the risk of other processes trying to use the file at the same time.

If not:

2. Is this possible in Windows at all? How about Unix?
3. Should I involve my database for this matter and lock on rows in the database instead, or is there a better way?
4. Another option I can see is repeating this piece of code, including a release of the lock before calling `unlink`, until `unlink` succeeds, but this seems a bit messy, right?

Comment: Humm, Idk, but try to close (`fclose`) the resource before `unlink`. I don't have a php server to test it right now.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Thank's for replying! I just tested with `fclose`, but unfortunately `fclose` seems to release the lock, which means other processes can lock on the file again...

Comment: That's what I mean. I don't remember if the lock (even in the same script) prevents or not the unlink.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Unfortunately it does seem to block `unlink`, even from the same script (and even without `flock($file, LOCK_EX);`, I think `fopen` automatically requests a shared lock)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm struggling with this too, 2 years later. Kind of seems dumb you can't acquire an exclusive lock on a file when trying to rename or unlink it, or at least the documentation isn't there for doing this.

One solution is open the file for writing, acquire an exclusive lock, clear contents of the file using ftruncate, close it, and then unlink it. When you're reading from the file, you can check the size to make sure the file has contents.

When deleting (untested code):

```
$fh = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'c'); // 'w' mode truncates file, you don't want to do that yet!
flock($fh, LOCK_EX); // blocking, but you can use LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB for nonblocking and a loop + sleep(1) for a timeout
ftruncate($fh, 0); // truncate file to 0 length
fclose($fh);
unlink('yourfile.txt');
```

When reading (untested code):

```
if (!file_exists('yourfile.txt') || filesize('yourfile.txt') <= 0) {
  print 'nah.jpg, must be dELeTeD :O';
}
```

Comment: `fclose` or `unlock` isn't needed before `unlink` because unlink removes directory entries rather than the file itself, the `fh` is still valid.